# What do I need the Error correction model for in the two step Engle Granger approach (bivariate Cointegration)

Tags: time-series, cointegration, pairs-trading

could someone kindly explain what I need the ECM for in a bivariate Cointegration test?

I am currently trying to reproduce the results of Rad et al. (2015): "The profitability of pairs trading strategies: distance, cointegration, and copula methods".

For the implementation of the Cointegration pairs trading strategy, the two step Engle Granger procedure is used. I understand that first, I can estimate the cointegration coefficient beta by doing an OLS estimation by regressing y(t) on x(t). In the case of bivariate cointegration, the OLS estimator would be superconsistent. Therefore, I understand that I need to test for Cointegration next, using the ADF test on the residuals. If the ADF test now tells me that the residuals are stationary and thus y(t) and x(t) are cointegrated, I would assume, that I proved that the two variables are cointegrated and I do also already have my coefficient beta.
I do not understand why I should still estimate an ECM, or what I should use the estimated ECM for respectively, because in the paper, it seems like they only test for cointegration and use beta fom then. However, they say that they use the Engle Granger two step method and estimate the ECM in the second step.

I could imagine that for some reason, I cannot use the beta estimated with OLS. Is that true? And if so, why can't I use it if it is superconsistent and tends to the true value?

Comment: Hi: If you were implementing a pairs trading strategy and wanted to decide when to enter a trade, the ecm  formulation would be one way to decide that. The cointegrating relationship that is estimated doesn't provide that.  Note that the cointegrating relationship is estimating the long term relationship between $y_{t}$ and $x_t$ whereas the ecm formulation is giving the dynamics between the short term change in $y_t$ and A) the short term change in $x_t$ and B) the current difference in the cointegrating relationship.

Comment: I don't have enough space ( nor the memory ) to write out the exact formula for the ecm but banerjee's text discusses the ecm in great detail.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for our support. The paper I am looking at uses another opening trigger for their trades. They just look at the normalized spread of the pairs and if this spread increases above 2, they open a trade. Therefore, it does not seem to me as if they would use the ecm to decide if they open a trade. Or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Hi and apologies for confusion. One doesn't have to use the ecm to decide when to trade. I was just giving that as an example of why would could find the ecm useful even if one has  estimated the cointegration relationship. The cointegration relationship shows the LONG TERM relationship between the two variables. (the levels relationship, namely $y_t = \beta x_t $). There is also a possible short term  change in $y_t$ which  can be caused by   A) changes in  $x_t$ and B) the level of dis-equilibrium in the long term relationship, namely $y_t - \beta x_t$.  This is what the ECM captures.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I understood it now

Comment: I'm glad it helped but it's best to examine the equation for the ecm and really dissect it in detail. Unfortunately,  I forget the details ( and it also depends on the number of lags of the change in $x_t$ that one uses ) but, on the RHS, one term is a coefficient multiplying $\triangle x_t$ and another term is a coefficient multiplying $(y_t - \beta x_t)$. The former captures the change in the response, $y_{t+1}$,  due to the change in $x_t$ . The latter captures the change in the response,  $y_{t+1}$, due to the current dis-equilibrium in the long term relationship of $y_t$ and $x_t$.

Comment: I highly recommend  Banerjee and Dolado's blue text ( publisher is palgrave ). It's been a long time but I remember almost the whole book being devoted to the ecm. Definitely it  takes slow reading and mindfulness but worth the trip.

Comment: I could not find a reasonable price on amazon ( maybe no longer in print ? ) but I did find it here and it's publicly available !!!!!!  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227467389_Co-Integration_Error_Correction_And_the_Econometric_Analysis_of_Non-Stationary_Data

Comment: Thank you again, I will definetely have a look on this!